# Python/Pandas Str.split returns NAN when there is no split

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a pandas dataframe with a column 'Target Pool'.
Sometimes this column has one value (the year) and sometimes has e values (the year, the quarter).
I want to split it up in to year and quarter. It works except, that if there is only the year, it returns NAN for the year. How can I split if necessary, and if not necesary retain the single word value?

Thanks

```
df[['Target Year', 'Target Quarter']] = df['Target Pool'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
display(df[['Target Pool', 'Target Year', 'Target Quarter']])

        Target Pool Target Year Target Quarter
0   2021    NaN NaN
1   2021    NaN NaN
2   2021    NaN NaN
3   2021 Q1 2021    Q1
4   2021 Q1 2021    Q1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is no whitespace to split over (i.e. with numeric values), `split` falls back and gives `NaN`. With a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cfkQJo/1) (might be more robust but might also be an overkill but here we go), you can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) (after converting the column to strings):

```
df[["Target Y", "Target Q"]] = (df["Target Pool"].astype(str)
                                                 .str.extract(r"^(\d+)\s*(Q\d)?$"))
```

which looks for one or more digits at the beginning (`^\d+`) to capture the year, then possible spaces (`\s*`) and optionally `Q{digit}` at the end (`$`) to capture the quarter value if it exists.

to get

```
>>> df
  Target Pool
0        2021
1        2020
2     2021 Q3
3     2020 Q1
4        2019
5     2020 Q4

>>> df[["Target Y", "Target Q"]] = df["Target Pool"].astype(str).str.extract(r"^(\d+)\s*(Q\d)?$")

>>> df
  Target Pool Target Y Target Q
0        2021     2021      NaN
1        2020     2020      NaN
2     2021 Q3     2021       Q3
3     2020 Q1     2020       Q1
4        2019     2019      NaN
5     2020 Q4     2020       Q4
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I see it works for you, but it still doesn't work for me. I get the same problem.  df[["Target Year", "Target Quarter"]] = df["Target Pool"].str.extract(r"^(\d+)\s*(Q\d)?$")
display(df[['Target Pool', 'Target Year', 'Target Quarter']])     Target Pool Target Year Target Quarter
0 2021 NaN NaN
1 2021 NaN NaN
2 2021 NaN NaN
3 2021 Q1 2021 Q1
4 2021 Q1 2021 Q1

Comment: @RichardFitzsimons Can you share the result of `df["Target Pool"].tolist()`? to see what really is in that column

Comment: [2021,
 2021,
 2021,
 '2021 Q1',
 '2021 Q1',
 2021,
 '2021 Q1',
 '2021 Q1',
 '2021 Q1',
 'Removed',

Comment: @RichardFitzsimons Oh, I see the column has some numeric values as well as strings. So `astype(str)` before extracting should do. I edited the answer.

Comment: @RichardFitzsimons `astype(str)` converts them all to strings so extracting works as expected.

Comment: Also works     :        df[['Target Year', 'Target Quarter']] = df['Target Pool'].astype(str).str.split(' ', expand=True)